# How can I center two columns in a row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 col-md-4 divs in one row div like so:

```
<div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-4">aaaa</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">bbbb</div>

</div>
```

My question is how do I center the col-md-4 div. I have 2 more rows above this that have 3 col-md-4 divs and this 3rd row creates and empty space because I have 2 and not 3. I hope what I am asking makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

try to add class `col-md-offset-2`. So you have "2-col space" before your columns.

So final code is:

```
<div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">aaaa</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">bbbb</div>

</div>
```